# Silverlight C#: How to filter a combobox based on another combobox?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, combobox, silverlight-5.0

**How to filter a combobox based on another combobox? ... again :)**

I'm writing an web app to learn. I'm using Visual Studio 2012, Silverlight 5, C#, and SQl Server for the data source.

I have one table loading into a datagrid and comboboxes to filter the datagrid. Up to this point everything is working just right.

The comboboxes are "FilterState" and "FilterWaterWay". Note they are not in the datagrid.

***I want to select a state and re-populate the FilterWaterWay with only those waterways in the state.***

I've seen a lot of ways to do this but none of them seem to match my setup. I could be wrong and just not know it.

From a learning standpoint, I would like to know how to implement this in all 3 of the following query data examples but I'll settle for just one. The last one is my favorite.

Thanks for any and all help.

---

I would not mind using the following to load comboboxes, filtered or not, but I can't firgure out how to

1. Restirct the GetQuery to only one field
2. Make that field distinct

This loads all data from the GetQuery to the datagrid.

```
LoadOperation<MASTER_DOCKS> loadOp = this._DocksContext.Load(this._DocksContext.GetMASTER_DOCKSQuery());

DocksGrid.ItemsSource = loadOp.Entities;
```

This loads all data from the GetQuery to the datagrid after it's been filtered

```
EntityQuery<MASTER_DOCKS> query = _DocksContext.GetMASTER_DOCKSQuery();

query = query.Where(s => s.WTWY_NAME == WaterwaytoFilterBy && s.STATE == StateToFilterBy);

LoadOperation<MASTER_DOCKS> loadOp = this._DocksContext.Load(query);

DocksGrid.ItemsSource = loadOp.Entities;
```

---

This is how I am currently loading the comboboxes. This works fine for the load but I don't see how to filter. 
The DomainService.cs does not know my other combobox (FilterState) that I want to use as the filter for this combobox (FilterWaterway).

If I could query the ObservableCollection in the xaml I might be able to get it to work but it seems kind of chunky.

Adapted from http://www.jonathanwax.com/2010/10/wcf-ria-services-datagrid-filters-no-domaindatasource-2/

XAML =

```
private ObservableCollection<string> waterWayFilterList;
    public ObservableCollection<string> WaterWayFilterList
    {
        get { return waterWayFilterList; }
        set { waterWayFilterList = value; }
    }


    private void DoPopulateFilter()
      {
             //Call Invoke Method to get a list of distinct WaterWays

       InvokeOperation<IEnumerable<string>> invokeOp = _DocksContext.FillWaterWayList();
           invokeOp.Completed += (s, e) =>
               {
                    if (invokeOp.HasError)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Failed to Load Category Filter");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Populate Filter DataSource
                        WaterWayFilterList = new ObservableCollection<string>(invokeOp.Value);

                        //Add a Default "[Select]" value
                        WaterWayFilterList.Insert(0, "[Select WaterWay]");


                        FilterWaterWay.ItemsSource = WaterWayFilterList;
                        FilterWaterWay.SelectedItem = "[Select WaterWay]";
                    }
                };
        }
```

DomainService.cs =

```
[Invoke]
        public List<string> FillWaterWayList()
        {

            return (from r in ObjectContext.MASTER_DOCKS

                    select r.WTWY_NAME).Distinct().ToList();

        }
```

---

Here's the closest I've gotten so far and it seems straight forward.

It returns no errors but the displayed result reads System.Collections.Generic.List'1[System.Char]

The record count in the dropdown is correct which leads me to think it's on the right track. 
Only what is displayed is wrong. A casting problem perhaps?

I would still have to get the result from the FilterState Combo box in where "TX" is.

```
var filter = from r in _DocksContext.MASTER_DOCKS
          where r.STATE.Equals("TX")
          select r.WTWY_NAME.Distinct().ToList();


MyComboBox.ItemsSource = filter;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without parentheses, you're doing the `.Distinct().ToList()` on the `string` (which implements `IEnumerable<char>`, which is why those operations work), which results in a `List<char>` (which isn't what you're looking for). You need to add parentheses so you get the distinct waterways:

```
var filter = (from r in _DocksContext.MASTER_DOCKS
          where r.STATE.Equals("TX")
          select r.WTWY_NAME).Distinct().ToList();
```

Note that if two waterways might have the same name, but actually be distinct, you'll need to instead select distinct `r`, and then differentiate them in the dropdown somehow, e.g.

```
var filter = (from r in _DocksContext.MASTER_DOCKS
          where r.STATE.Equals("TX")
          select r).Distinct().ToList();

// generated classes are partial, so you can extend them in a separate file
public partial class MASTER_DOCKS
{
    // the dropdown uses the ToString method to show the object
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0} ({1})", WTWY_NAME, ID);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well Rats! That was way to easy :) Thank you, Tim and if I could up vote you I would. I'll ask another question about why I should even use ObservableCollection over this example. It doesn't appear that I need it.